# How to get the time recv() takes to receive something?

Tags: python, sockets, synchronization

I'm trying to make a server send a command to a client like "start this", but I want to give specific time to that. Let say "start this in 10 seconds". 
What I need now is to calculate how long it took to the message to arrive at the client and subtract 10 seconds, so the client will start the thing in the desired time by the server.

Let say the server sends "start this in 10 seconds" and it takes 2 seconds to get to the client by recv(), now the client will wait 8 seconds and do what has been asked to.

I have read many questions about synchronization, NTP, but I haven't had success on those. Do I need to sync server and client clocks? Or is this approach I'm thinking suffice? If it's enough, how to get the time it takes to receive something with recv() from when it left server to when the client got it??

Comment: Usually on the internet today you are having a packet round time trip of something like 10 to 300 ms depending on the distance and number of hops. So, if you tell the client to start in 10 s it might be 10,01 to 10,3 s. In general the variations in the network will always have a large effect, expect it to be 10% of the RTT when the network works well, much more when not. In the second case any synchronization would be a waste of time.

Comment: Unless you are sending something via satellite? :)

Answer (score 1):

If your network's latency is low enough (or your timing-accuracy requirements are loose enough) that you can safely ignore the network latency, then sending a "execute in 10 seconds" command is sufficient.  Of course, in that scenario, you could equally well just wait 10 sends and then send an "execute now" command, too.

Since you're asking the question, however, you probably want a solution that still gives you good synchronization timing even in the face of high latency or variable latency.  To get that, synchronized clocks are the only really reliable way to go.  If the two computers' clocks are synchronized, then you can send a command like "execute this command at 3:02PM exactly" at any time(*), and then be pretty confident that the remote computer will actually execute the command at 3:02 PM.  NTP might be sufficient for your needs, or if you need very high accuracy (e.g. to within microseconds), check out [ptpd](http://ptpd.sourceforge.net) as an alternative.

If you don't want to get into formal clock synchronization, but still want something better than just hoping that your network latency is small enough to ignore, one other approach is to send test messages from one computer the other every so often.  The test message should include in its data payload the sending computer's current system time at the moment the message was sent, and the receiving computer should immediately echo that timestamp back verbatim in its reply message.  When the sending computer receives the reply, it can then subtract the timestamp found in the reply packet from its current system time, to calculate an estimated round-trip time.  Divide that value by two and you've got an estimated one-way trip time, which you can then use to modify your delay times to (hopefully) compensate for the network delay.  Note that this approach has two shortcomings that limit its accuracy, though:  (1) it assumes that network delay is relatively constant (which is not necessarily the case, especially if you are sending data over TCP where dropped packets may cause occasional significant latency spikes due to resends and enforced FIFO data ordering), and (2) it assumes that the network is symmetrical -- i.e. that packets going in one direction take about the same amount of time as packets coming back in the other direction; an assumption that may or may not be true depending on how the network is set up.

(*) well, any time sufficiently before 3:02 PM, of course, where "sufficiently before" would be a function of your network's expected worst-case latency.